# Cannot name background thread, Void error

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to name my thread, I have this code

```
 public void DownloadFromUrl(final String fileName) {  //this is the downloader method
               new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Looper.prepare();
...
```

but when I try to name it like this

```
 public void DownloadFromUrl(final String fileName) {  //this is the downloader method
                   Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            Looper.prepare();
...
```

it just says

```
Required: Java.lang.Thread 
Found: Void
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you called the `start` method on the thread. This returns `void`. 
Try this instead.

```
 Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Looper.prepare();
                        ...
 }
 t1.start();
```

But I agree with the other answer, you probably should use somethine else other than threads.

Answer (score 1):

try to use AsynkTask for downloading instead of thread

Look as this [AsynkTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)